# How do you move an admin menu item in Magento

Tags: magento

I currently have an extension that I created and it currently sits inside of its own top level menu. I would like to move it so that the item would appear inside of the Customers menu.  Does anyone know how to do this?

It looks like this is handled inside the extensions config.xml file.  The code that I have for it right now is as follows:

```
<menu>
    <testimonials module="testimonials">
        <title>Testimonials</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
        <children>
            <items module="testimonials">
                <title>Manage Items</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>testimonials/adminhtml_testimonials</action>
            </items>
        </children>
    </testimonials>
</menu>
```

I tried changing the title element to Customers and it just created a duplicate Customers menu.

Comment: Nice question, Josh. Thanks for the answer Joseph. Very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<menu>
    <customer>
        <children>
            <testimonials module="testimonials">
                <title>Testimonials</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <items module="testimonials">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>testimonials/adminhtml_testimonials</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </testimonials>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
```